# Error with optimality in Iterative Deepening Depth First Search algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

I have implemented a version of Rush Hour (the puzzle board game) in Python as a demonstration of some AI algorithms. The game isn't important, because the AI is relatively independent of its details: I've attempted to implement a version of iterative deepening depth first search in Python as follows (note that this code is almost directly copied from Russell and Norvig's AI text, 3rd edition, for those of you who know it):

```
def depth_limited_search(game, limit):
    node = GameNode(game)
    frontier = []
    #frontier = Queue.Queue()
    frontier.append(node)
    #frontier.put(node)
    frontier_hash_set = set()
    frontier_hash_set.add(str(node.state))
    explored = set()
    cutoff = False
    while True:
        if len(frontier) == 0:
        #if frontier.empty():
           break
        node = frontier.pop()
        #node = frontier.get()
        frontier_hash_set.remove(str(node.state))
        explored.add(str(node.state))
        if node.cost > limit:
            cutoff = True
        else:
            for action in node.state.get_actions():
                child = node.result(action)
                if str(child.state) not in frontier_hash_set and str(child.state) not in explored:
                    if child.goal_test():
                        show_solution(child)
                        return child.cost
                    frontier.append(child)
                    #frontier.put(child)
                    frontier_hash_set.add(str(child.state))
    if cutoff:
        return 'Cutoff'
    else:
        return None

def iterative_deepening_search(game):
    depth = 0
    while True:
        result = depth_limited_search(game, depth)
        if result != 'Cutoff':
            return result
        depth += 1
```

The search algorithm, as implemented, does return an answer in a reasonable amount of time. The problem is that the answer is non-optimal. My test board of choice has an optimal answer in 8 moves, however this algorithm returns one using 10 moves. If i replace the lines above commented out lines with the commented lines, effectively turning the iterative deepening depth-first search into an iterative deepening breadth-first search, the algorithm DOES return optimal answers!

I've been staring at this for a long time now trying to figure out how a simple change in traversal order could result in nonoptimality, and I'm unable to figure it out. Any help pointing out my stupid error would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd look at the computation of costs, not included here, since this code looks OK at first sight, and you're getting results with the wrong cost values, after all.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have been more explicit. The 'cost' of a node is just the number of moves taken to reach it; the child generated by node.result(action) has cost equal to node.cost + 1. Also, show_solution() prints out the series of moves taken to reach the goal node, so it seems unlikely that the cost is wrong as I can just count the steps.

Comment: Why so many convertion to str?

Comment: The set needs immutable keys.

Comment: Instead of just staring at it, why don't you step it through with a debugger to see how the algorithm is behaving

Comment: Aren't strings immutable? I have so many `str(board.state)` because it's the simplest way I could think of to hash the state uniquely (define a `__str__()` function in the state class, and use string's built in `__hash__()` ). Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Whoops, just realized that a dabbler was responding to Paulo, not commenting on the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test this but I think the problem is this predicate:

```
if str(child.state) not in frontier_hash_set and \
   str(child.state) not in explored:
```

The problem is that earlier in this DFS iteration, `child.state` may have been inserted into the frontier or set of visited states, but with a **greater cost**.

```
S -> A -> B -> C -> G
 \            /
  \-----> D -/
```

Obviously you will not reach the goal with limit < 3. But when limit = 3, your DFS may first visit A, B, and C. Then when it backtracks to S, visits D, and tries to visit C, it will not push C onto the stack because you visited it earlier.

To fix this, I believe you need to "un-visit" states as you backtrack. Implementation-wise it is probably easiest to write your algorithm recursively and pass copies of your explored-state set in a functional style.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code finds a sub-optimal solution is simply because of the way depth-first-search and bread-first-search work.

A breadth-first-search will try *all* possible 8-move solutions before trying *any* 9-move solutions, so a breadth-first-search *must* find a solution with the fewest possible moves.

In contrast, a depth-first-search will try some 9, 10, 11, ... move solutions before it has exhausted all possible 8-move solutions and so may come up with a sub-optimal result.

For example, given a game tree that looks like this:

```
          1
     /         \
    2           3
  /   \       /   \
 4     5     6     7
 /\    /\    /\    /\
8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
```

The code as given will call `goal_test` on the nodes in this order: 2, 3, 6, 7, E, F, C, D, 4, 5, A, B, 8, 9. Note that nodes E and F are tested before the children of node 6, and also before the children of node 2. This is a depth-first-search.

The alternate version of your code will call `goal_test` in this order: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F. This is a bread-first-search.

**Edit:** My bad, my order of calls to `goal_test` above is only correct for the final iteration in `iterative_deepening_search`. The actual order of calls to `goal_test` is 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, E, F, C, D, 4, 5, A, B, 8, 9. I verified this by actually running the code, so I'm 100% sure it is now correct.

Are you sure the `child.state` value is unique for each game node? If they are not, then the algorithm will fail. For example, consider what happens if node 4 has the same state as node 6. In that case your code will call `goal_test` on nodes in this order: 2, 3, 2, 3, 6, 7, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, E, F, C, D, 5, A, B. Note that `goal_test` is *never* called on nodes 4, 8 and 9.

But if we switch to the alternate version of your code then `goal_test` is called in this order: 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, A, B, E, F. Now `goal_test` is not called on nodes 6, C and D! I believe this may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I don't use depth first search, though. The algorithm given above implements iterative deepening depth first search, which is a modified version of depth first search, but it's modified in a way that causes it to search all moves of depth 8 before any moves of depth 9, etc. It is optimal, like breadth first search, but only uses linear memory, like depth first.

Comment: To clarify, the order of calls to `goal_test` in my algorithm should be:
2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, A, B, 3, 6, C, D, 7, E, F

Comment: I stand corrected and have edited my answer above. Are you sure the child.state values are unique? See my edits for more on that.